# An incorrect even gets triggered if the browser back button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, postback, autopostback

Here's my aspx page

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text="suff goes here" /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnClick" ID="btn" Text="Click me!" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChanged" 
                  AutoPostBack="true">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
    </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And here's the code behind

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
}

protected void ddlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
```

When I click something in the dropdown, I get redirected to Page2, I then click the browser back button, and click the "Click Me!" btn. Instead of the `btnClick` even getting fired, it fires `ddlChanged` first, and does the redirect again.

Can this be solved without javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a session variable and store the last value in the dropdown, so when it fires you are like double-checking that effectively the dropdown.SelectedIndex change

```
protected void ddlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If the var is NULL then it is the first time the event gets triggered
    if (Session["lastDropDownValue"] != null)
        //If it has a value, and also is the same selected index, then it really doesn't change
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastDropDownValue"].ToString()) == ddl.SelectedIndex)    
            return; 

    //Set your variable for future validations 
    Session["lastDropDownValue"] = ddl.SelectedIndex;
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am realizing that I can't really get away without client side javascript, since I need to have the selected dropdown value get reset when a back button is hit.